# How to check swap between elements if user is logged in or not

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So here is my navigation header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="176dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="John Doe"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="johndoe@gmail.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I've used a fake `username`, `email` and `picture`.
How may I check if user is logged in or not then HIDE/Show login button instead of data ?
I want to show the "Register /Login" Button if the user is NOT logged in.
I'm using `firebase`. So I know I can use the `auth` to check it.

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();  
if (currentUser != null) { 
  //Logged in
} else { 
  // NOT logged in
}
```

But I don't know how/where to make the condition and how to change it.
1- Show his picture/username/email if logged in;
2- Show the login/register button/link if not logged in.

Current code ( Following Peter's answer)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //User login elements
    ImageView userAvatar = findViewById(R.id.user_avatar);
    TextView userNickname = findViewById(R.id.user_nickname);
    TextView userEmail = findViewById(R.id.user_email);
    TextView registerLink = findViewById(R.id.link_cadastrar);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MessageFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_message);
    }


    // Listen to user login
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user != null) {
                // NOT LOGGED IN
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            }
            else {
                // LOGGED IN
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }

        }
    };

}
```

App Crash wi the following error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$AuthStateListener)

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: Sorry, dude. I Was studying for a test. I'll try it today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check if the user is logged in or not:

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();  
 if (currentUser != null) { 
   //Logged in
  } else { 
   // NOT logged in
  }
```

Then to show the email/username/picture if he is logged in, you can use [`setVisibility`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

Add an id for each widget:

```
android:id="@+id/userProfilePic"
android:id="@+id/email"
android:id="@+id/userName"
```

then do:

```
 userProfilePic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 email.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Where would be the right place to write the backend code? Main Activity? Also, should I get those elements with `getElementById`? Before or inside `onCreate()` function ?

Comment: Also, the app crash on startup when I try to `currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();  ` No idea why

Comment: `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();` this has to be above `mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);` since `mAuth` is not referencing any object in heap using the code that you have written.

Comment: Working !! But when I do `userEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);` or `View.INVISIBLE` but the element still visible. Already Rebuilded the project.

Comment: userEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE); `userEmail` should be the id of the EditText

Comment: I'm finishing the login right now. But with the way your showed me, I'm able to hide/show the right elements when the user is NOT logged in. Thanks a bunch, Peter !